# Webform replacements using %post[key] for Array variables

Tags: webforms, tokens

I'm trying to set a default value for a hidden field capturing a POST Array Variable (by the way, webform form keys are arrays) but the literal is not replaced with the posted value.

Should I escape/encode the field key in %post[key] when the variable is an array?

e.g
`%post[submitted[participant_details][contact_details][name]]`

This does not work.
I also tried url-encoding the brackets inside the key like this:

`%post[submitted%5Bparticipant_details%5D%5Bcontact_details%5D%5Bname%5D]`

This does not work either.
Instead, adding %post[form_id]  (form_id:non-Array form variable) in the same field works as described.

> **EDIT**
>   I figured this out finally. The arrays were previously filtered out. There is a recent patch for everyone interested http://drupal.org/node/824606